# как добавить к серверу секундомер?

Tags: java, websocket

есть `websocket` сервер и клиент, сервер есть однопоточный и многопоточный. есть написанный код `stopwatch`.
как сделать так, что бы когда клиент подключался к серверу у него открывался написанный уже код `stopwatch`?
`stopwatch` реализован простыми `jframe` и `swing`.

upd
код клиента

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class keks_client {

    /**
     * 
     * @param args
     * @throws InterruptedException
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
  

// zapusk   
        try(Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", 3345);  
                BufferedReader br =new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
                DataOutputStream oos = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                DataInputStream ois = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream()); )
        {

            System.out.println("Client connected to socket.");
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("Client writing channel = oos & reading channel = ois initialized.");            

          
                while(!socket.isOutputShutdown()){

                   
                    if(br.ready()){

// vse proshlo                     
            System.out.println("Client start writing in channel...");
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            String clientCommand = br.readLine();
            
            oos.writeUTF(clientCommand);
            oos.flush();
            System.out.println("Clien sent message " + clientCommand + " to server.");
            Thread.sleep(1000);
      
           
            if(clientCommand.equalsIgnoreCase("quit")){
           
                System.out.println("Client kill connections");
                Thread.sleep(2000);
         
                if(ois.read() > -1)     {   
                    System.out.println("reading...");
                    String in = ois.readUTF();
                    System.out.println(in);
                            }
               
                break;              
            }
         
            System.out.println("Client sent message & start waiting for data from server...");          
            Thread.sleep(2000);

       
            if(ois.read() > -1)     {   
                     
            System.out.println("reading...");
            String in = ois.readUTF();
            System.out.println(in);
                    }           
                }
            }

            System.out.println("Closing connections & channels on clentSide - DONE.");

        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

как и куда интегрировать в этот код `stopwatch`?
upd
сделал так, как я думал сработает.
код действия `MonoThreadClientHandler` (класс выполняющий действия в случае написания определенных символов в консоль клиента):

```
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.security.KeyStore.Entry;

import stopwatch.Stopwatch;

public class MonoThreadClientHandler implements Runnable {

    private static Socket clientDialog;

    public MonoThreadClientHandler(Socket client) {
        MonoThreadClientHandler.clientDialog = client;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        try {
            DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(clientDialog.getOutputStream());

// chtenie socketa
            DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(clientDialog.getInputStream());
            System.out.println("DataInputStream created");

            System.out.println("DataOutputStream  created");

            // usloviya //

            while (!clientDialog.isClosed()) {
                System.out.println("Server reading from channel");
                String entry = in.readUTF();

                // vvod v konsol entry
                System.out.println("READ from clientDialog message - " + entry);

                // proverka vvoda 
                
                if (entry.equalsIgnoreCase("quit")) {

                    // esli quit  server otvechaet
                    System.out.println("Client initialize connections suicide ...");
                    out.writeUTF("Server reply - " + entry + " - OK");
                    Thread.sleep(3000);}
                   
                    else if (entry.equalsIgnoreCase("start")) {
                        System.out.println("Enjoy stopwatch :) ");
                        Thread.sleep(2000);
                        
                        Stopwatch stopwatch = new stopwatch();
                            break;
            }
           
                // esli vvod ne vverniy, eho

                System.out.println("Server try writing to channel");
                out.writeUTF("Server reply - " + entry + " - OK");
                System.out.println("Server Wrote message to clientDialog.");

                // bufer
                out.flush();

                // v nachalo
            

            // end usloviya //

            System.out.println("Client disconnected");
            System.out.println("Closing connections & channels.");

            // kanali socketa
            in.close();
            out.close();

            
            clientDialog.close();

            System.out.println("Closing connections & channels - DONE.");
            catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

при вводе start выводит только сообщение Enjoy stopwatch :) и выключает сервер.
upd
прикрепил код `stopwatch`.

```
package stopwatch;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Stopwatch implements ActionListener{


        JButton button = new JButton("knopka");
        JFrame frame_timer = new JFrame();
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JButton startButton = new JButton("СТАРТ");
        JButton resetButton = new JButton("СБРОС");
        JLabel timeLabel = new JLabel();
        int elapsedTime = 0;
        int seconds =0;
        int minutes =0;
        int hours=0;
        boolean started = false;
        String seconds_string = String.format("%02d", seconds);
        String minutes_string = String.format("%02d", minutes);
        String hours_string = String.format("%02d", hours); 
    
        Timer timer = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {
            
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                
                elapsedTime=elapsedTime+1000;
                hours = (elapsedTime/3600000);
                minutes = (elapsedTime/60000)%60;
                seconds = (elapsedTime/1000)%60;
                seconds_string = String.format("%02d", seconds);
                minutes_string = String.format("%02d", minutes);
                hours_string = String.format("%02d", hours);
                
                timeLabel.setText(hours_string+":"+minutes_string+":"+seconds_string);
            }
            
            
        });
        
        public Stopwatch(){
            
            timeLabel.setText(hours_string+"-"+minutes_string+"-"+seconds_string);
            timeLabel.setBounds(100,100,200,100);
            timeLabel.setFont(new Font("Verdana",Font.PLAIN,35));
            timeLabel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createBevelBorder(1));
            timeLabel.setOpaque(true);
            timeLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.CENTER);
    
            startButton.setBounds(100,200,200,50);
            startButton.setFont(new Font("Calibri",Font.PLAIN,20));
            startButton.setFocusable(false);
            startButton.addActionListener(this);
            
            resetButton.setBounds(100,250,200,50);
            resetButton.setFont(new Font("Calibri",Font.PLAIN,20));
            resetButton.setFocusable(false);
            resetButton.addActionListener(this);
            
            frame.add(startButton);
            frame.add(resetButton);
            frame.add(timeLabel);
            
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setSize(420,420);
            frame.setLayout(null);
            frame.setVisible(true);
            
            frame_timer.add(timeLabel);
            frame_timer.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame_timer.setSize(420,420);
            frame_timer.setLayout(null);
            frame_timer.add(timeLabel);
            frame_timer.setVisible(true);
        }


        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            
            if(e.getSource()==startButton) {
                start();
                if(started==false) {
                    started=true;
                    startButton.setText("СТОП");
                    start();
                }
                else {
                    started=false;
                    startButton.setText("ПРОДОЛЖИТЬ");
        
                    stop();
                }
            }

                        if(e.getSource()==resetButton){
                started=false;
                startButton.setText("СТАРТ");
                reset(); }
                }
    
        
void start() {
    timer.start();
    }
void stop() {
    timer.stop();
}
void reset() {
    timer.stop();
    elapsedTime=0;
    seconds=0;
    minutes=0;
    hours=0;
    seconds_string = String.format("%02d", seconds);
    minutes_string = String.format("%02d", minutes);
    hours_string = String.format("%02d", hours);
    timeLabel.setText(hours_string+":"+minutes_string+":"+seconds_string);
}
}
```

Comment: не понятно, что, как, куда

Comment: Прикрепи к вопрос код класса `stopwatch` т.к. ты создал объект, но что внутри него я не очень понимаю.

Comment: Вообще, что бы `JFrame` показался надо вызвать у него метод `setVisable`